The men feel they "were/have been" used when their girlfriends finish the food and do not want to chat with them. - Are they different?
Example 1

The men feel they were used when their girlfriends finish the food and do not want to chat with them.

Example 2

The men feel they have been used when their girlfriends finish the food and do not want to chat with them.

This is a generic statement. Which tense should I use?
I have a feeling that this is another difference between American English and British English?

You're right that AmE more often uses the simple past in cases where BrE would use the present perfect, but in this case both varieties would agree on the present perfect. The first sentence, with "were," sounds wrong because it would imply "the feeling of having been used" happened at a time earlier than the end of the meal.

Just remove the definite article if you wish to make a generic statement. "Men feel..."   There's no difference between BrE and AmE here.   The use of the definite article in the sentence is odd throughout. "The food"?

These 'men' sound like fools, or overgrown infants.

Men feel used (taken advantage of)  when their dates eat dinner [at a restaurant ] in total silence (without making conversation).

If you'd like feedback on grammar and tenses, you should choose topics that don't evoke reactions like the above comment "These 'men' sound like fools, or overgrown infants."  Maybe post on the 'psychology' or 'interpersonal' stack sites.

Here are some more definite articles to chew on: Sometimes the food is better than the conversation.

@QuackE.Duck "When their girlfriends finish the food and do not want to chat with them, the men feel they were used."   Does this one work?

@VinceL In that variant, you've switched around the order of the two clauses, putting the adverbial clause before the main one. This doesn't change anything about what sequence of tenses fits best, so the simple past ("were used") still isn't ideal there. The present perfect ("have been used") makes the most sense, but the simple present or present continuous could also work if, instead of describing a specific event, you're making a general statement about people's attitudes. So, you might say [continued]

"When their girlfriends finish the food and do not want to chat with them, the men feel they are used." (This sounds formal, possibly overly so; better would be the continuous variant: "...feel they are being/getting used.") Neither of these variants is actually preferable to "...have been" though, even for making a general statement.

The OP should use the Present Simple to express a truth; e.g. They live in Montana; Identical twins don't have the same fingerprints, or a fact (including assumptions) e.g. The best-selling car in Italy is the Fiat Panda; Americans measure temperature only in Fahrenheit.
The OP's declarative sentence seems to convey the idea that men who invite women out to dinner feel used ("used" is an adjective in this instance) when their date refuses to engage in conversation. It's a familiar complaint in forums and dating websites; however, it's not so much the conversation that is lacking, but the sexual favors…
The OP could use the Simple Past if they were reporting the findings of a questionnaire that was taken at a specific point in time. When the research was conducted should be mentioned previously.

The men (surveyed in 2018) felt they were used when their girlfriends finished a meal and did not want to chat with them.

The Present Perfect is used when we want to focus on the results of something that happened in the past. The time is not specified.

Men have felt used when their girlfriends finish dinner and do not want to chat with them.

The OP should use the Present Simple if they want to express a conception (a truth).
Men (no article) feel used when their girlfriends eat dinner at a restaurant [probably paid by the suitor] and do not want to chat with them.
Paraphrased:

Men feel used when their date eats dinner in total silence.

